# How to set name to vector by splitting element?

Tags: r

```
v<-c('f1=q1+q2+q3','f2=q4+q5+q6','f03=q7+q8')
```

I want to split above vector's element,`strsplit('f1=q1+q2+q3', '=')`,and use `f1`,`f2`,`f3` as name of vector,the expect result as below:

```
> c(f1='q1+q2+q3',f2='q4+q5+q6',f3='q7+q8')
        f1         f2         f3 
"q1+q2+q3" "q4+q5+q6"    "q7+q8"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.table` to read the data into two columns by specifying the `sep` as `=`, and then create a named vector with `setNames` using those columns

```
with(read.table(text = v, sep="="), setNames(V2, V1))
#     f1         f2        f03 
#"q1+q2+q3" "q4+q5+q6"    "q7+q8"
```

---

Or if we use `strsplit`, bind them to a single data.frame with `rbind` and then set the names

```
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(v, "=", fixed = TRUE))
setNames(out[[2]], out[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
#names
v1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(v, '='),function(x) x[1]))
#formula
v2 <- do.call(cbind,lapply(strsplit(v, '='),function(x) x[2]))
#create vector
vectoro <- v2[1,]
names(vectoro) <- v1[,1]

       f1         f2        f03 
"q1+q2+q3" "q4+q5+q6"    "q7+q8"
```